# Cumulative tiered rate calculation in SQL Server for DML UPDATE/INSERT trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, calculated-columns

Essentially, using SQL Server, I want to take the "Gross Amt" from the current table below (which is derived from a computed column upon `INSERT` or `UPDATE`) and then have that "Gross Amt" run through the "Tiered Table" to derive the "Total A $" in the desired output table.

I figured this would likely need to be done with a trigger (maybe a function?) since this calculation would happen upon `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and because the conditional logic could be incorporated into it since there are different tier tables with different Min/Max values and percentage thresholds for different tiers.

The example below is, of course, cumulative, and functions like marginal income tax rates, the first 10000 is at 90% (for Total A), the second tier calculates the 19999 at 60%, the third 69999 at 40%, and so on, etc. There are other regions with different tiers that are just simple lookup reference values.

Tiered table:

| RegionID | TierNo | Min | Max | Total A | Total B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 10000 | .90 | .10 |
| 3 | 2 | 10001 | 30000 | .60 | .40 |
| 3 | 3 | 30001 | 100000 | .40 | .60 |
| 3 | 4 | 100001 | 500000 | .40 | .60 |
| 3 | 5 | 500001 | 999999999999 | .20 | .80 |

Current table sample:

| TransID | RegionID | GrossAmt | Total A % | Total A $ | Net Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 3 | 125000 |  |  |  |

Desired output:

| TransID | RegionID | GrossAmt | Total A % | Total A $ | Net Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 3 | 125000 | 0.47 | 59000 | 66000 |

Any ideas or guidance would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your tiers aren't quite right. For example, the first one begins at `0` and ends at `10000`, but the next one starts at `10001`, leaving anything between `10000` and `10001` unaccounted for. Instead, have your tiers abutting each other, and pick your intervals carefully using `> AND <=`.

Secondly, **this doesn't need a trigger at all.** You should just calculate this on the fly when you need it. Create a view or an inline Table Valued Function if you need to.

It looks like a fairly simple grouped join, which you can do neatly using `CROSS APPLY`. You just need to calculate how much to multiply for each tier: the lower of `GrossAmt` or `Max`, subtracting `Min`

```sql
SELECT
  c.*,
  [Total A %] = t.Total / c.GrossAmt,
  [Total A $] = t.Total,
  [Net Amt]   = c.GrossAmt - t.Total
FROM CurrentData c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Total = SUM((v.ActualMax - t.Min) * t.[Total A])
    FROM Tiers t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
      CASE WHEN c.GrossAmt < t.Max THEN c.GrossAmt ELSE t.Max END
    )) v(ActualMax)
    WHERE c.GrossAmt > t.Min
) t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99624e41cfa02df1c6de95fcbeaa2905)

You can do this as an inline Table Valued Function if you want.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTieredTotal (@GrossAmt decimal(18,9))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    SELECT
      Total = SUM((CASE WHEN @GrossAmt < t.Max THEN @GrossAmt ELSE t.Max END - t.Min) * t.[Total A])
    FROM Tiers t
    WHERE @GrossAmt > t.Min
;
```

You can then change the main query to

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  [Total A %] = t.Total / c.GrossAmt,
  [Total A $] = t.Total,
  [Net Amt]   = c.GrossAmt - t.Total
FROM CurrentData c
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetTieredTotal (c.GrossAmt) t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this and apologies for the late response. This is exactly what I'm interested in. Now, I would like to have the flexibility to incorporate a tiered lookup value as well within the TBV if the amount is just a ranged lookup value as opposed to a cumulative calc. Is it possible to write a TBV that gives both and returns one based on a conditional in the query's WHERE clause?

Comment: Sounds like you need something like `WHERE @LowerGrossAmt < t.Max AND @UpperGrossAmt > t.Min` along with associated `SUM((CASE` calculation, but hard to say without full details. I suggest you create a *new* question for that